# Magento 2 : Can not get Customer ID after Cache is enabled

Tags: magento2, cache, magento-2.1, customer-session

I am Fetching **CustomerId** using

```
  public function getCurrentCustomerId()
    {

        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();

    }
```

But **After cache is enabled no id is returned** (This was a known [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2010) and was said to solved in Magento 2.1 but still facing the issue)

Answer (score 2):

In 2.1, I'm pretty sure you can use `Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer` to retrieve the current customer when cache is enabled.

Indeed, this class provides a method called `getCustomer` that seems to behave differently whether or not the cache is enabled:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_PageCache')
        && !$this->request->isAjax()
        && $this->view->isLayoutLoaded()
        && $this->layout->isCacheable()
    ) {
        return $this->getDepersonalizedCustomer();
    } else {
        return $this->getCustomerFromService();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried "$this->_currentCustomer->getCustomer()->getId();" Still the problem persists

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar hmm that's weird. What if you call `getCustomerId` ?

Comment: No luck with this as well  , as soon as i turn on cache using 'bin/magento  cache:enable' , there is no id. i am using EE , 2.1 was supposed to solve all these issues :(

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar you're using EE ? Well I don't have access to an EE instance unfortunately I guess my knowledge stops here

Comment: CE and EE have the same code base i guess , at-least these core functionality . Thanks for looking into issue you are always very helpful and active

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar feel free to create a new issue on github by explaining in details what you've tried and what does not work I hope you'll get your problem fixed

Comment: This might be something you have resolved already because the post is months old. This is not a bug, but intended behavior. When the Page Cache (but partially also the cache) is enabled, Depersonalize Plugins kick in to remove session-specific information from certain models like the customer. Instead of relying upon the customer session within your own code, try to use the documented procedure of Private Content: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();
$customerDetail = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerDetail->getById($customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
```